# Updated: How can I loop through HTML img tags to make a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a wordpress site that uses gravity forms and gravityview to make car sale listings, in these forms on the home page users can submit images and information of their cars. I want to take these user submitted images and put them dynamically on a seperate listings page in slideshows. Now I have succesfully made a slideshow and been able to pull the images dynamically using a shortcode but have been unsuccesfull into having the images in the listings so they appear/displayed.

The problem seems to be that when I use a shortcode to pull the images all of the images are in the shortcode and all of them get displayed in the slide. Whilst in the page code they're all in seperate tags, I don't know how to differentiate each slide with a picture. Or how to loop through all the images tags with the according slide. This is the link to the listings page https://autoverkoop1.nl/listings-pagina/

Here is the code I tried just a basic slideshow, that tries to pull the images dynamically by using a shortcode for the images as the source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 10</div>
    <img src="{Image Hopper:123}" style="width:90%">
    <div class="text">Links voorkant</div>
</div>
</div>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When you try this the images from the forms get all pulled dynamically, but they all get put together in each slide.

```
<p> <img decoding="async" src="<a href=" https:="" autoverkoop1.nl="" index.php?gf-download="2023%2F05%2FImage2.jpeg&amp;form-id=6&amp;field-id=123&amp;hash=b53736f18a14d3e50340cab25e7bc50aca890e91ebf87df657885c11310e2e87&quot;" target="_blank" aria-label="Klik om te bekijken"><img decoding="async" style="max-width:100%; padding: 5px" src="https://autoverkoop1.nl/index.php?gf-download=2023%2F05%2FImage2.jpeg&amp;form-id=6&amp;field-id=123&amp;hash=b53736f18a14d3e50340cab25e7bc50aca890e91ebf87df657885c11310e2e87"><br><a href="https://autoverkoop1.nl/index.php?gf-download=2023%2F05%2FImage11.jpeg&amp;form-id=6&amp;field-id=123&amp;hash=6f742e9e3dda48e86799539bc2d5252b5810c19c420c8985b09012eaee91fd0e" target="_blank" aria-label="Klik om te bekijken"><img decoding="async" style="max-width:100%; padding: 5px" src="https://autoverkoop1.nl/index.php?gf-download=2023%2F05%2FImage11.jpeg&amp;form-id=6&amp;field-id=123&amp;hash=6f742e9e3dda48e86799539bc2d5252b5810c19c420c8985b09012eaee91fd0e"></a><br><a href="https://autoverkoop1.nl/index.php?gf-download=2023%2F05%2FImage51.jpeg&amp;form-id=6&amp;field-id=123&amp;hash=e7512fc2660b036e988e4dc14c2e6f5e7a647a072c04021eb8f1add59c75191a" target="_blank" aria-label="Klik om te bekijken"><img decoding="async" style="max-width:100%; padding: 5px" src="https://autoverkoop1.nl/index.php?gf-download=2023%2F05%2FImage51.jpeg&amp;form-id=6&amp;field-id=123&amp;hash=e7512fc2660b036e988e4dc14c2e6f5e7a647a072c04021eb8f1add59c75191a"></a><br></p>
```

As you can see all the images are in seperate  tag. And I would probably be looking for a loop to go through the images individually so they get presented with each according slide. So it should look like slide1 == img1, slide2 == img2, etc... Or any other solution/help to get the images to appear on the page in the listings would also be greatly appreciated.

PS: The example code only works on the first submission on the page the one with: Kavelnummer:319. And you should open the first listing on a seperate page to get a better view.